# Insert on mysql from filesystem

Tags: mysql, debian

I need to insert the name of files from specif folder on my database.

I use Debian, and i have a folder with some images:

```
ss:~/folder_img$
859034809583_img.jpg
458389547389_img.jpg
...
```

How can i take this images like string and insert in specif `mysql` table?

I have no ideia, and search for this not a ready script.

Any tip?

Comment: Is this a recurring thing or a one time job?

Comment: one time for now....tks for atention

Answer (score 1):

You can use python

here's an example:

```
import mysql.connector
import os

directory = '/home/usr/folder_img'

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='test', password='test',
                               host='127.0.0.1',
                               database='images')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    query = ("INSERT INTO images (imagename) VALUES (%(image_name)s)")
    data = {'image_name': filename}
    cursor.execute(query, data)

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: note that you have to install python and python-mysql on you machine first.